# Unable to parse selector?

Tags: javascript, python, scrapy, splash-screen, scrapinghub

I am currently using scrapy + splash + python in centos. I have write following code for extracting content from [here](https://careers.us.samsung.com/careers/svc/app/viewSearchJob).

Unable to extract data from the java script popup windows for example "href="javascript:void(0);" any one guide me to crawl.

spider code:

```
def parse(self,response):
        selector = Selector(response)
        links = []
        for link in selector.css('div.job_list div.cont > span.style.display:block;vertical-align: bottom;::attr(href)').extract():
            yield Request(urlparse.urljoin(response.url, link),
                          callback=self.parse_listing_page,
                          #meta={"use_splash": False}
                          )
```

Following Error:

```
[testtim@dpitstsvr015 samsungcom]$ scrapy crawl samsung
2014-11-11 18:05:33+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Scrapy 0.24.4 started (bot: samsungcom)
2014-11-11 18:05:33+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Optional features available: ssl, http11
2014-11-11 18:05:33+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Overridden settings: {'NEWSPIDER_MODULE': 'samsungcom.spiders', 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN': 1, 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1, 'RETRY_ENABLED': False, 'SPIDER_MODULES': ['samsungcom.spiders'], 'BOT_NAME': 'samsungcom'}
2014-11-11 18:05:33+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled extensions: LogStats, TelnetConsole, CloseSpider, WebService, CoreStats, SpiderState
2014-11-11 18:05:33+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares: HttpAuthMiddleware, DownloadTimeoutMiddleware, UserAgentMiddleware, DefaultHeadersMiddleware, MetaRefreshMiddleware, HttpCompressionMiddleware, RedirectMiddleware, CookiesMiddleware, SplashMiddleware, ChunkedTransferMiddleware, DownloaderStats
2014-11-11 18:05:33+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares: HttpErrorMiddleware, OffsiteMiddleware, RefererMiddleware, UrlLengthMiddleware, DepthMiddleware
2014-11-11 18:05:33+0530 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines: 
2014-11-11 18:05:33+0530 [samsung] INFO: Spider opened
2014-11-11 18:05:33+0530 [samsung] INFO: Crawled 0 pages (at 0 pages/min), scraped 0 items (at 0 items/min)
2014-11-11 18:05:33+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6023
2014-11-11 18:05:33+0530 [scrapy] DEBUG: Web service listening on 127.0.0.1:6080
https://careers.us.samsung.com/careers/svc/app/viewSearchJob
http://localhost:9999/render.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcareers.us.samsung.com%2Fcareers%2Fsvc%2Fapp%2FviewSearchJob

2014-11-11 18:05:58+0530 [samsung] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://localhost:9999/render.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcareers.us.samsung.com%2Fcareers%2Fsvc%2Fapp%2FviewSearchJob&wait=2&images=0> (referer: None)
2014-11-11 18:05:58+0530 [samsung] ERROR: Spider error processing <GET http://localhost:9999/render.html?url=https%3A%2F%2Fcareers.us.samsung.com%2Fcareers%2Fsvc%2Fapp%2FviewSearchJob&wait=2&images=0>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py", line 824, in runUntilCurrent
        call.func(*call.args, **call.kw)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 638, in _tick
        taskObj._oneWorkUnit()
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/task.py", line 484, in _oneWorkUnit
        result = next(self._iterator)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 57, in <genexpr>
        work = (callable(elem, *args, **named) for elem in iterable)
    --- <exception caught here> ---
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 96, in iter_errback
        yield next(it)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/offsite.py", line 26, in process_spider_output
        for x in result:
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/referer.py", line 22, in <genexpr>
        return (_set_referer(r) for r in result or ())
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/urllength.py", line 33, in <genexpr>
        return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/contrib/spidermiddleware/depth.py", line 50, in <genexpr>
        return (r for r in result or () if _filter(r))
      File "/home/sureshp/Downloads/samsungcom/samsungcom/spiders/samsung.py", line 24, in parse
        for link in selector.css('div.job_list div.cont > span.style.display:block;vertical-align: bottom;::attr(href)').extract():
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/selector/unified.py", line 110, in css
        return self.xpath(self._css2xpath(query))
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/scrapy/selector/unified.py", line 113, in _css2xpath
        return self._csstranslator.css_to_xpath(query)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cssselect/xpath.py", line 192, in css_to_xpath
        for selector in parse(css))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cssselect/parser.py", line 355, in parse
        return list(parse_selector_group(stream))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cssselect/parser.py", line 370, in parse_selector_group
        yield Selector(*parse_selector(stream))
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cssselect/parser.py", line 396, in parse_selector
        next_selector, pseudo_element = parse_simple_selector(stream)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cssselect/parser.py", line 477, in parse_simple_selector
        **"Expected selector, got %s" % (peek,))
    cssselect.parser.SelectorSyntaxError: Expected selector, got <DELIM ';' at 48>**

2014-11-11 18:05:58+0530 [samsung] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2014-11-11 18:05:58+0530 [samsung] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
    {'downloader/request_bytes': 314,
     'downloader/request_count': 1,
     'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1,
     'downloader/response_bytes': 111927,
     'downloader/response_count': 1,
     'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
     'finish_reason': 'finished',
     'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 11, 12, 35, 58, 732318),
     'log_count/DEBUG': 3,
     'log_count/ERROR': 1,
     'log_count/INFO': 7,
     'response_received_count': 1,
     'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
     'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
     'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
     'spider_exceptions/SelectorSyntaxError': 1,
     'splash/unwrapped': 1,
     'splash/wrapped': 1,
     'start_time': datetime.datetime(2014, 11, 11, 12, 35, 33, 902315)}
2014-11-11 18:05:58+0530 [samsung] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`div.job_list div.cont > span.style.display:block;vertical-align: bottom;::attr(href)` is not a valid CSS selector.

Try:

```
'div.job_list div.cont > span[style="display:block;vertical-align: bottom;"]::attr(href)'
```

Note that `::attr(href)` is a Scrapy extension to CSS selectors, to select attribute values using a pseudo-element syntax.